# What does npm WARN excluding symbolic link mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

What does `npm WARN excluding symbolic link` mean? And how do I make it go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is emitted when `npm` interacts with a TAR file.

When it detects that a symbolic link is being used, it will emit the warning. For example, an archive you're trying to install through `npm` may contain a symbolic link. Those links will not be created on your local file system and are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

That errors are normally caused by cache issues, after you clean cache they should disappear.

Just run `npm cache clear`.